# Strange difference in absolute positioning between figure and div tags

Tags: html, css, sass, css-position

I have implemented some css rules to practice. All right, but I am in troubles with a percentage deviation of an absolute positioned element `left:5%`. I have observed that when I use the `figure` tag  it doesn't work properly, instead it works with `div` element. For understand the problem you have to resize, to scale back the page. The deviation from left side of the viewport is different between the two versions.I would like to understand why and how to fix the problem (in the figure version).
I posted the code and the jsfiddle for both versions.

```
<html lang="it">

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
 <!--  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> Non si mette perchè non ho istruzioni reponsive precise come media query-->
<meta name="description" content="Sito con intestazione con sfondo. Esercizio si rifa al libro css master, esercizio finisched-example.html del capitolo 5">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Cat Page</title>

<style type="text/css">
  body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  }

  .sfondo-intro {
    position: relative;
    /*margin:0; servirebbe per h1 che ha un margine di default,non per header*/
    height: 600px;
    /*perche senza contenuto h1 non visualizza lo sfondo*/
    background-image: url(https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/4457/MeXAJj.jpg);
    background-position: 50% 30%;
    /*per mantenere il gatto centrato quando ridimensiono la finestra*/
    background-size: cover;


  }

  .profile-box {
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    bottom: -60px;
    -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
    border-radius: .5em;
    padding: .5em;
  }

  .profile-box img {
    max-width: 100%;
    /*max-width a differenza di width fa si che l'immagine sia larga al massimo quanto è larga l immagine. Prova a mettere width:400px ad esempio in .profile-box per vedere che succede (l immagine non si espande fino a 400px)*/
    height: auto;
    /*Altezza settata in modo da continuare a rispettare l aspect ratio dell immagine*/

  }

  .didascalia {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
    font-weight: 600;
  }

</style>

 </head>



  <body>

<header class="sfondo-intro" role="banner">
  <div class="profile-box">
    <img src="https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/606/oMPbxW.jpg" alt="Charles The Cat" />
    <figcaption class="didascalia">@CharlesTheCat</figcaption>
  </div>

  </header>
  </body>

</html>
```

[Code with div](https://jsfiddle.net/5uhe6mvL/)

And here there is other version with figure element in place of div element

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html lang="it">

 <head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
<!--  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> Non si mette perchè non ho istruzioni reponsive precise come media query-->
<meta name="description" content="Sito con intestazione con sfondo. Esercizio si rifa al libro css master, esercizio finisched-example.html del capitolo 5">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Cat Page</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  }

  .sfondo-intro {
    position: relative;
    /*margin:0; servirebbe per h1 che ha un margine di default,non per header*/
    height: 600px;
    /*perche senza contenuto h1 non visualizza lo sfondo*/
    background-image: url(https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/4457/MeXAJj.jpg);
    background-position: 50% 30%;
    /*per mantenere il gatto centrato quando ridimensiono la finestra*/
    background-size: cover;


  }

  .profile-box {
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    bottom: -60px;
    -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
    border-radius: .5em;
    padding: .5em;
  }

  .profile-box img {
    max-width: 100%;
    /*max-width a differenza di width fa si che l'immagine sia larga al massimo quanto è larga l immagine. Prova a mettere width:400px ad esempio in .profile-box per vedere che succede (l immagine non si espande fino a 400px)*/
    height: auto;
    /*Altezza settata in modo da continuare a rispettare l aspect ratio dell immagine*/

  }

  .didascalia {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
    font-weight: 600;
  }

   </style>

 </head>



<body>

<header class="sfondo-intro" role="banner">
  <figure class="profile-box">
    <img src="https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/606/oMPbxW.jpg" alt="Charles The Cat" />
    <figcaption class="didascalia">@CharlesTheCat</figcaption>
  </figure>

</header>
</body>

</html>
```

[Second version with figure](https://jsfiddle.net/52ybho4u/)

Comment: figure comes with default margin

Comment: Awesome. I added margin:0;    and now it works.I could never figure it out by myself. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tags come with default styling from the use-agent, and the figure element has some margins. You can use an inspector like the google developer console (ctrl+i on Chrome, on window or linux) to inspect what styles are applied to a element and debug this kind of stuff, but usually when the same css works differently with different tags, this is usually the case.

Adding `margin: 0` to your figure would solve it in this case.